# How can I instantiate a new hasMany Eloquent relationship with at least one empty model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model (let's call it `PageModel`) with a `hasMany` relationship (let's call it `rulesList`). When I create a new `PageModel`, I want to default `rulesList` with at least one empty model. How can I do this in Eloquent?

Code Sample:

```
// Normal instantiation
$this->rulesList; // Equals NULL

// I can set it manually like so, but is that right?
$this->rulesList = Collection::make([new RulesListModel]);
// NOTE: Doing this does not create an empty model when PageModel is output as JSON
```

Comment: So you want to create a collection out of your model ? Why ? It may work, but it depends do you want to use RulesModel somewhere else ?

Comment: @carousel it sounds to me like cmfolio wants to guarantee that when output as JSON PageModel always has an entry for rulesList even if it's empty. (And for no other useful reason, just JSON ouput.)

Comment: Yes, that's why I was asking. Model is a standalone unit, and he should have good reason to provide it to Collection like this.

Comment: In Eloquent with Laravel, when you have a `hasMany` relationship and results are returned, it is turned into a Collection. This is why I thought making a Collection manually is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't (to my knowledge) a way to do this within the relationship itself. The reason is that an eloquent model is defined by the database query return values.

You could set up some sort of null row in your database, but I would advise against that.

One way that may work: I think it is possible to create an eloquent model without running a query. I think something like `EloquentModel::fill($attributes)` would do it. Where `$attributes` is an array of attributes for your model e.g. `array('title' => null, 'description' => null);`

You'd have to create this manual model and then add it to your relationship.